# How to process file sequentially using Spring Integration File Inbound Adaptor

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have requirement to read the files from the source directory and process it sequentially (one by one).

I have below application context configuration,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <int:channel id="controlChannel" />

    <int:channel id="adapterInputChanel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel" />

    <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundAdapter"
        directory="inputdir"
        channel="adapterInputChanel" auto-startup="false" prevent-duplicates="true"
        ignore-hidden="true">
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"
            max-messages-per-poll="1">
        </int:poller>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>


    <int:service-activator input-channel="adapterInputChanel"
        ref="mainService" method="readFiles" output-channel="filesOut">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="500" />
    </int:service-activator>

    <bean id="mainService" class="com.sample.MainService">

    </bean>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"
        directory="output dir" />

</beans>
```

As per above configuration, file inbound adapter will get one file per poll and execute the service executor.

But meanwhile if the system is getting another file then the file inbound adapter should not trigger the service again until the first transaction is finished.

Please let me know the way to handle this issue with some samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<queue/>` from `adapterInputChanel` and remove the `<poller/>` from the service activator.

Then, the channel will be a `DirectChannel` and your service will run on the adapter's poller thread and the next file won't be processed until the service exits.

You can read about [different channel types here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel); specifically the difference between subscribable and pollable channels.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am using control bus to start/stop these polling process like below,
controlChannel = ac.getBean("controlChannel", MessageChannel.class);
SubscribableChannel adapterInputChanel = ac.getBean("adapterInputChanel", SubscribableChannel.class);
controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@inboundAdapter.start()"));
  But the problem is if i stop the adapter, the respective service is terminating immediately. In this case the file inbound adaptor should only stop the further polling.  Could you please advise me on this.

Comment: Stopping the adapter won't affect the current thread, unless it does something that is interruptible. If it does, you could use a [smart poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling) to defer the stop - use the control bus to send a message to your poller to tell it to stop the adapter when the poll returns `null` (or before the next poll, depending on your requirements).